# How to retrieve a Long from Oracle using java

Tags: java, oracle

I have a database where a Long datatype has an image stored in it,
I want to retrieve it and write it to an image file,

I tried using getBytes method and write a file using for and it return as corrupt image,

I also tried using getBinarystream and write using fos I wrote it in an image file I get same corrupt error.

Code:

```
InputStream is = RS.getBinaryStream(1);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("image.bmp");
Int c;
While((c=is.read())!=-1)
{
fos.write(c);
}
fos.close;
```

Comment: You have a `Long` type containing an image? Why `Long` and not a binary type like blob? Also your posted code is not Java.

Comment: Are you sure the `Long` column contains a valid image? If it has been written incorrectly then you will get an invalid image regardless of whether you are reading the binary data correctly or incorrectly.

Comment: Yes the Long contains a valid signature image,

Comment: Also Tom to answer your question this is an old architecture where we have used long to store the image and what I have posted is just a code snippet for retrieving the image

Comment: How do you store an image in a Long? What is the format?

Comment: A code snippet with broken code isn't helping.

Comment: What is **RS** in `InputStream is = RS.getBinaryStream(1);`?

Answer (score 0):

To store binary data you should use LONG_RAW or a BLOB. The type LONG is for character based (text) data.